# How can I apply a patch to Gnome manually?

Tags: gnome, patch

I have this bug: [gvfsd-afp-browse](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=710490). I have Ubuntu 14.04 and bug is not fixed in this, or in 14.10. Last post in bug report indicates it is possible to manually patch. How would I go about doing so?