# How do I apply a GNOME patch?

Tags: gnome, patch

You can see my most recent question has to do with a GNOME bug. There's a patch for it. [How can I apply a patch to Gnome manually?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/544726/how-can-i-apply-a-patch-to-gnome-manually) was never answered!

Come on Ubuntu community!

Definitely needed with the complete move of Canonical to GNOME by default.

Comment: I looked at bug 710490.  Those patches are for source files.  So after downloading all the original source files, you would apply the patch to those.  Finally, you would have to build the project.

Comment: Applying the patch is straightforward.  Download the patch file, let's call it PATCH_FILE_NAME.patch.  Then locate the file that you want to patch, let's call it FILE_TO_PATCH.  With these two files, you execute the command:  patch FILE_TO_PATCH PATCH_FILE_NAME.patch.  But as I mentioned previously, the  files in the bug you are looking at do not look like binary patches, so you will still have to compile.

Comment: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=788188

These are runtime js files. No compilation necessary. However, please include the recompile commands in your answer for completeness.

Lots of stuff needs to come before a/js/ui/keyboard.js, but it's not specified.

It is not obvious how to obtain a .patch. I clicked on the attachments' names, details, diff, and review, and none are download links to .patch files.

Is sudo required?

A step-by-step answer will help all the future 17.10 ubunt-nubs to patch GNOME problems for years to come.

Comment: @PJSingh Please make a complete answer.

Comment: @PJ Singh hello?